# How do I have Python return an abstract expression of a function and get the parameters in it?

Tags: python, function

Assume I defined a function

```
def pdf(x_1, x_2):
    return ((x_1 ** 2.0) * ((1.0 - x_2) ** 3.0)) + (((1.0 - x_1) ** 3.0) * (x_1 ** 2.0) * (1.0 + x_2) ** 3.0)
```

Is there a way for me to return the fully expanded abstract expression of function `pdf`, like the following

```sh
2.0 * x_1 ** 2.0 - 3.0 * x_1 ** 3.0 + 3.0 * x_1 ** 4.0 - x_1 ** 5.0 - 9.0 * x_1 ** 3.0 * x_2 + 9.0 * x_1 ** 4 * x_2 - 3 * x_1 ** 5.0 * x_2 + 6.0 * x_1 ** 2.0 * x_2 ** 2.0 - 9.0 * x_1 ** 3.0 * x_2 ** 2.0 + 9.0 * x_1 ** 4.0 * x_2 ** 2.0 - 3.0 * x_1 ** 5.0 * x_2 ** 2.0 - 3.0 * x_1 ** 3.0 * x_2 ** 3.0 + 3.0 * x_1 ** 4.0 * x_2 ** 3.0 - x_1 ** 5.0 * x_2 ** 3.0
```

Also, is it possible to return the coefficients and powers in each term as well? Is everything described above even doable in Python? Or should I seek to use Mathematica?

Any advice will be welcome! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This cannot be done with any arbitrary function, but the [SymPy](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/basic_operations.html) library should let you do this in a fairly straightforward way for algebraic expressions. To use your example above:

```
import sympy
x_1, x_2 = sympy.symbols("x_1 x_2")
pdf = ((x_1 ** 2.0) * ((1.0 - x_2) ** 3.0)) + (((1.0 - x_1) ** 3.0) * (x_1 ** 2.0) * (1.0 + x_2) ** 3.0)
expanded = sympy.expand(pdf)
print(expanded) # x_1**2.0*(-x_1 + 1.0)**3.0*(x_2 + 1.0)**3.0 + x_1**2.0*(-x_2 + 1.0)**3.0
example_solution = pdf.subs(x_1, 3).subs(x_2, 5) # -16128.0000000000
```